# Moving BAM SSIS Packages in Package Store on SQL Server

Tags: ssis, biztalk, biztalk-bam

Will this break BAM and is it possible to fix it again, possibly with updating any config files that can point to the new locations?

Where would such config files be assuming this is how it's likely to be structured?